# Is there a direct way- a cft to list all lambda functions for a particular region?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I want to have a cloud formation template to list all lambda functions for a particular region. I don't need to write a lambda code using list-function and call it inside my CFT.

I tried incorporating CLI command inside CFT but it didn't work

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do with that list? What happens when new functions are added or old ones removed over time?

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to directly add a aws cli command in a cloudformation template. Either you will have to create a EC2 instance and then run the CLI command in the user data or create a lambda backed custom resource to do it.

Both will complicate the simple CLI command.

```
aws lambda list-functions --region eu-west-1
```

CFN is just an orchestration tool. It cannot compute on itself.

Instead we can use a simple lambda python script and invoke the same in the CFT

```
import boto3

#Create an lambda client
client = boto3.client(
    "lambda"
)

    response = client.list_functions(
    MasterRegion='string',
    FunctionVersion='ALL',
    Marker='string',
    MaxItems=123
)

print(response)
```